# Should I use spaces or None in list of characters which should be joined in python?

Tags: python, list, repr

I'm writing a program in python where I use a list which represents a board of tic tac toe.

Since I was asking myself if I should use "None" or single spaces for free spaces, I've written these two pieces of code:

```
   #code 1:     
   list1 = [None, 'X', 'O']
   print( '|'.join(value or ' ' for value in list1) )

   #code 2:
   list2 = [' ', 'X', 'O']
   print( '|'.join(list2) )
```

I find list1 better and more elegant to handle than list2, but it has the drawback of being (just a bit) less comfortable to print out.

So I'm writing here to ask if there's any good reason to use the second code over the first.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form maintains a distinction between the value of an empty cell in your app - `None` and its *representation* - an empty space.  While this doesn't matter much in a trivial program, it's important in larger applications.  So use the first form to maintain good habits.